# Change property of controls child object by using Styles or DataTemplate in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a button and I have an image (though it could be any controls) inside of it:

```
<Button Width="150" Height="80">
    <Image Source="..." Width="50" Height="50" />
</Button>
```

I want to change the style of button when mouse is over it and make it so that I could also change properties of the image inside when it happens.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />

            <!-- Here I want to change alignment of the image inside the button if there is one -->
            <Setter Property="Image.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But it doesn't work this way, and for some reason any child controls start to change alignment, not only images but also text and other controls. The other things I tried just didn't compile. Probably DataTemplate should be used; I'm new to WPF and XAML and I still don't understand it enough and couldn't find what I need yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `HorizontalContentAlignment` to set the content alignment of a button:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
```

**Based on your comment below**, I can give an example:

```
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Width="150" Height="80">
        <DockPanel Height="80" Width="150"><!-- A more complex control here-->
            <Image Width="50" Height="50">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="50" UriSource="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9eae4ae63d70142e81f0365de42474ae?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Image"><!-- The style target to the image control only in the button control -->
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!-- Binding to IsMouseOver of the button-->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: it works in this case, but what if I have some custom controls with their custom properties? how do I change them on MouseOver over the button?

Comment: You could have a look at those questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10127740/1360389 https://stackoverflow.com/q/24065023/1360389